# Setting PYTHONPATH environment variable in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, python, windows, visual-studio-2012

I have a C++ program which imports a Python module, along the lines of this snippet:

```
#include <Python.h>

char python_module[] = "my_module";

Py_Initialize();
PyObject* pName;
pName = PyString_FromString(python_module);
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
```

However the module needs to be on the `PYTHONPATH` for this line to actually load the module. On Mac or Linux this is relatively straightforward - set `PYTHONPATH` on the term you are running the compiled program from. Is there a way to do this for Visual Studio C++? Setting the `PYTHONPATH` windows environment variable hasn't helped.

Comment: Setting the environment variable should be fine, but be aware that if you're debugging this in VS2012, you need to restart the IDE *after* setting the environment variable because it reads them only on start up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is scheme to setup module search path:

1. The script location; the current directory without script.
2. The PYTHONPATH variable, if set.
3. For Win32 platforms (NT/95), paths specified in the Registry.
4. Default directories lib, lib/win, lib/test, lib/tkinter; these are
   searched relative to the environment variable PYTHONHOME, if set, or
   relative to the executable and its ancestors, if a landmark file
   (Lib/string.py) is found, or the current directory (not useful).
5. The directory containing the executable.

You probably need to restart IDE to get it working.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer - the error actually proved unrelated, but your answer is indeed the correct one to the question asked.